# Transcoding from amr to flac using JAVE (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, amr, flac

I want to transcode amr audio files to flac using [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/) which uses ffmpeg.

The transcoding procedure runs successfully on Windows but fails on Linux (centOS).

I checked the JAVE code and found it uses the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.amr -vn -acodec flac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f flac -y 1.flac
```

the output is:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r11179, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-pp --enable-swscaler --enable-pthreads \
--enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora \
--enable-memalign-hack --extra-ldflags=-static -lm -lz
libavutil version: 49.5.0
libavcodec version: 51.48.0
libavformat version: 52.1.0
built on Dec  7 2007 15:35:14, gcc: 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)

Input #0, amr, from '1.amr':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0.0: Audio: samr / 0x726D6173, 8000 Hz, mono
Input #1, amr, from '1.amr':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1.0: Audio: samr / 0x726D6173, 8000 Hz, mono

Output #0, flac, to '1.flacffmpeg':
  Stream #0.0: Audio: flac, 8000 Hz, mono, 64 kb/s
Output #1, flac, to '1.flac':
  Stream #1.0: Audio: flac, 8000 Hz, mono, 64 kb/s

Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Stream #1.0 -> #1.0

Unsupported codec (id=73728) for input stream #0.0
```

So the problem is an unsuppported codec? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If JAVE is bundling a copy of FFmpeg then there's not much you can do beyond filing a bug report.

Alternately, since you can see the FFmpeg command they're using, you could always compile it yourself, with all the necessary codecs, and run the same external command.